# Expressing Oracle LISTAGG() functionality in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, oracle11gr2, listagg

Consider the following PL/SQL query:

```
SELECT department_id, LISTAGG(last_name, '; ')
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY last_name) "Emp_list"
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id;
```

Would would be LINQ equivalent of the above?
Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `string.Join` ( [Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join) ) ?

Comment: Yes, but what you also want to return other columns from the table? Please refer to the update SQL.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Since you want other columns and want to group, you can't use the method I originally proposed as-is. Here's a new solution, though the generated SQL isn't exactly great:

```
from employee in employees
group employee by employee.department_id into grpEmployee
select new {
    DepartmentId = grpEmployee.Key,
    LastNames = string.Join(", ", employees.Where(e => e.department_id == grpEmployee.Key)
                                  .OrderBy(e => e.last_name).Select(e => e.last_name))
}
```

Note that this method combines both the query-like and lambda syntax.

---

This should do the trick. We select all of the last names and then join them into a single string as the final result.

```
string.Join("; ", (from employee in employees
                   where employee.department_id == 30
                   orderby employee.last_name
                   select employee.last_name))
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I should have provided a more elaborate example, where not just a combined string is returned, but some other columns as well. I updated the SQL statement in my question.

Comment: Thank you, but that does not seem to work: ``System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call) ...``

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, except instead of `employees.Where(...`, you'll need `grpEmployee.Where(...`